# Linux router with multiple gateways and port forwarding

Tags: nat, linux-networking, port-forwarding, gateway, nic

I want to use a Linux VM to act as several routers at once. I have multiple servers hosting different services and dedicated public IP for each of them.

Super simplified setup example:

1. Ubuntu server (14.04.01)

> eth0: ISP1a 5.0.0.2 port forwarding to 10.0.0.102
>      eth0:1 ISP1b 5.0.0.3 port forwarding to 10.0.0.103
>      eth1:  ISP2 5.0.1.4 port forwarding to 10.0.0.104
>      eth2   local  10.0.0.2
>      eth2:1 local 10.0.0.3
>      eth2:2 local 10.0.0.4

2. SRV-102

> IP: 10.0.0.102
>      GW: 10.0.0.2

3. SRV-103

> IP: 10.0.0.103
>      GW: 10.0.0.3

4. SRV-104

> IP: 10.0.0.104
>      GW: 10.0.0.4

I can't figure out how to make packets go this way:

> ISP1a -> eth0 -> eth2 -> local
>      ISP1b -> eth0:1 -> eth2:1 -> local
>      ISP2 -> eth1 -> eth2:2 -> local
>      local with 10.0.0.2 as GW coming on eth2 -> eth0 -> ISP1a
>      local with 10.0.0.3 as GW coming on eth2:1 -> eth0:1 -> ISP1b
>      local with 10.0.0.4 as GW coming on eth2:2 -> eth1 -> ISP2

Comment: You need to use iproute2 to support multiple default routes (multi wan).  I don't have time to provide a detailed answer, but [this site may help](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html).

Comment: I tried that and also found another article online but still all machines route out through eth0. I've changed the question to include details about virtual adapters as is my case.